# JDBC DriverManager.getConnection vs DriverManager.registerDriver() difference?

Tags: java, jdbc

What is difference between `DriverManager.getConnection vs DriverManager.registerDriver()` when calling oracle function?

I often used `DriverManager.getConnection` only but i saw example in oracle site with DriverManager.registerDriver().

So

1. which i should use when calling oracle function?
2. When to use DriverManager.registerDriver()?

Comment: The DriverManager does not have a register() method.  It has a registerDriver() method which you use to manually register a JDBC driver.  Generally you don't need to do this manually.  You can do a Class.forName() on the driver class and it will register itself.

Comment: sorry that was typo edited to DriverManager.registerDriver()

Comment: In any case, those two methods are used to do different things.  One returns a connection using a registered driver, one registers a new driver.

Comment: You really need to acquaint yourself with the API docs so you can do a little self-help.  http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/DriverManager.html.

Comment: Unless you develop a JDBC driver, then you have - normally - no reason to ever call `DriverManager.registerDriver`. JDBC drivers register themselves. And the javadoc of both methods adequately describe what they do. Please read the documentation, it is provided for a reason.

Comment: From JDBC 4.0, no longer need to explicitly load JDBC drivers...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These two methods are completely different. You should have asked difference between Class.forName() vs DriverManager.registerDriver().
Anyways,

**DriverManager.registerDriver() :**

> Registers the given driver with the DriverManager. A newly-loaded
>   driver class should call the method registerDriver to make itself
>   known to the DriverManager.

Ref :  http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/DriverManager.html#registerDriver(java.sql.Driver)

`getConnection()` is used for creating the connection once the driver gets loaded

Answer (score 1):

With JDBC 4 The DriverManager methods getConnection and getDrivers have been enhanced to support the Java Standard Edition Service Provider mechanism.

When the method getConnection is called, the DriverManager will attempt to locate a suitable driver from amongst those loaded at initialization and those loaded explicitly using the same classloader as the current applet or application.

You can find the more in the java docs https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/DriverManager.html